# Correct way to type a 'setState' function using React hook useState()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm working with React and typescript and just stumbled upon a dilemma. I use `React.useState()` hook to manage my state like this:

```js
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = React.useState({} as User)  // currentUser is of type User
```

I found this way to type the `setCurrentUser` function:

```js
setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User>>
```

So if I try to use this function with an invalid parameter like a string I get this error:

> `Argument of type '"dummy string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<User>'`

Then I found an easier way:

```js
setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<User>
```

With this way the error message is easier to read too:

> `Argument of type '"dummy string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'`

So witch one is the correct/official way to type this `setState` hook function ?

Comment: `const [a, setA] = useState<User>();` You don't need to type the action, it's typed by itself as `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User | undefined>>`

Comment: @GlenCarpenter No `User` is a self written interface. But the error here is intentional to show you what typescript give me for error message

Comment: @ritaj True but think is that I store this function in a react `Context`. And because I need to type everything that is in this `Context` I need the type of this hook function ;)

Comment: Well then it's `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User>>`

Comment: @ritaj Ok thanks but what is the differrence between `React.Dispatch<User>` ? Because TypeScript don't seem to make any difference and the second one is more pleasant

Comment: Because `SetStateAction` can also be a function that receives previous state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per React definitions:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

In your example:

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User>> =
| React.Dispatch<User>
| React.Dispatch<(prevState: User) => User>;
```

That means you can either do this:

```
setUser({ name: 'UserName'});
```

Or use a previous value:

```
setUser(previousUser => {
  return {
    ...previousUser,
    surname: 'UserSurname'
  }
});
```

By declaring the dispatch as `setUser: React.Dispatch<User>`, you can't use the second version.

Comment: Ah but yes of course now I see the difference :) Thank you very much for your response